# Ignore error with CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two fields

```
CallLength(varchar(10)) and 
CallLengthActual(varchar(10))
```

which contains values in the format hh:mm:ss.

I need to find the difference between the two fields in seconds which works fine when the data is formatted correctly. Some of the data is formatted incorrectly and when I try cast it as integer I'm getting the error message "conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int."

Is there any way to just ignore the data that isn't formatted correctly?  I'm using SQL Server 2012 and the docs say TRY_CAST is supported but it doesn't seem to work with my version.

```
(CAST((SUBSTRING([CallLength],0,(CHARINDEX(':',[CallLength],0)))*3600)+(LEFT(RIGHT([CallLength],5),2)*60)+RIGHT([CallLength],2) AS int) -
CAST((SUBSTRING([CallLengthActual],0,(CHARINDEX(':',[CallLengthActual],0)))*3600)+(LEFT(RIGHT([CallLengthActual],5),2)*60)+RIGHT([CallLengthActual],2) AS Int)) AS Variance
```

Comment: Please check your DB compatibility level. I gues it is lower than 110. `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;`

Comment: What error do you get when you attempt to use TRY_CAST?

Comment: When you say try_cast doesn't work, what error are you getting?

Comment: Well, unless you have values exceeding 24 hours, you should store them as `Time`, not as `varchar`. If you do have values exceeding 24 hours, I would suggest convert them to number of seconds **before** storing them in the database and just store as `int`.

Comment: compatibility_level  from sys.databases = 100

Comment: TRY_CAST isn't even a supported function

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by that @user3641053, but it most certainly is a supported function: [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide sample data and desired results, but your code looks way more complicated than need be.

If I were getting the difference in seconds, I would simply do:

```
   datediff(second,
            try_convert(time, CallLengthActual),
            try_convert(time, CallLength)
           ) as diff_seconds
```

This may be the negative of what you want.  I'm not sure what you are subtracting from what.

If `try_convert()` doesn't work, then your compatibility level is set to an older version.  You can get pretty close with `isdate()`:

```
   datediff(second,
            (case when isdate(CallLengthActual) = 1 then convert(time, CallLengthActual end),
            (case when isdate(CallLength) = 1 then convert(time, CallLength) end)
           ) as diff_seconds
```

Comment: TRY_CONVERT works but TRY_CAST doesn't.  This simplified approach is much better than mine.  Thanks

Comment: @user3641053 if `TRY_CONVERT` works, then `TRY_CAST` will as well; they were both made available in SQL Server 2012. if the latter isn't working, it likely means your syntax is incorrect.